# Logic App - XPath - Extract element based on child value

Tags: xpath, azure-logic-apps

I have a problem with my process in Logic Apps.
I am calling a SOAP web service and get an xml response.
In the response, there are 2 namespaces: env: and wd:

In the original process (Workday), I would use the following transformation to extract the element that I need:

```
        <xsl:for-each select="wd:Email_Address_Data[wd:Usage_Data/wd:Type_Data[@wd:Primary='1']/wd:Type_Reference[@wd:Descriptor = 'Work']]">
            <xsl:value-of select="wd:Email_Address"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

In logic app, I understand that I can use the local-name() to avoid namespace issue, but I do not seem to understand how to use that in this part:

```
[wd:Usage_Data[@wd:Public='1']/wd:Type_Data[@wd:Primary='1']/wd:Type_Reference[@wd:Descriptor = 'Work']]
```

Or Would there be an easier way than xpath to replicate the above in Logic App?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Below is the example to use the XPath.

This XPath,

```xml
//Context[Type = "test2"]/Value
```

will select all `Value` element children of `Context` elements of `Type` `test2`.

For further information check the [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59955695).

Also check the related [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67556803) and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54737091)

Comment: how is this even relevant to my question? My question is not how to do XPath expression but how to convert it to Logic Apps with their local-name() and whatnot expression